# Bumblebee : Module bbswitch could not be loaded

Tags: nvidia-optimus, vga, bumblebee, bbswitch

I've upgraded to 12.04 and I had to switch from Ironhide to the latest version of Bumblebee.

Now, when I try to run `bumblebeed`, I get this error:

```
FATAL: Module bbswitch not found.
[ERROR]Module bbswitch could not be loaded (timeout?)
[WARN]No switching method available. The dedicated card will always be on.
```

I don't really need to use the secondary VGA on Kubuntu, so I would like to find a way to definitely shut the discrete GPU down and avoid wasting battery. I can't disable it from the BIOS because I use it on Windows. My card is an nvidia 540M.

Answer (score 10):

`bbswitch` is the kernel module that is used for disabling the nvidia GPU. Be sure to install the Bumblebee PPA as described in [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969). Installing Bumblebee from that PPA also retrieved the `bbswitch-dkms` package. If you do have this package installed, the likely reason of failure that the kernel headers for the installed kernel are missing.

In that case, update your kernel including headers:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Reboot. If the problem still persists, try explicitly installing the headers for the *loaded* kernel:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

If the module is still not loaded, try removing bbswitch completely and reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get purge bbswitch-dkms
sudo apt-get install bbswitch-dkms
```

Comment: I've followed the official Bumblebee guide to install it, and I've got the `bbswitch-dkms` package.

I've tried `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` and it says that I've got the latest version of `linux-headers-3.2.0-24-generic`.

Is there any way to blacklist nVidia drivers and have it shut down when I boot Kubuntu?

Comment: @StepTNT Try reinstalling bbswitch as described in the updated answer. If you are only interested in power saving, you could create a new question for that.

Comment: Confirming that this also worked for me today on Debian, my laptop fan isn't releasing warm air anymore and battery life is longer.

Comment: Excuse me what is the difference between bbswitch and bbswitch-dkms?

Comment: @AlirezaMohamadi "bbswitch" is the name of the kernel module. DKMS is a framework that will automatically rebuild kernel modules to match installed kernel versions. The "-dkms" packages include the necessary kernel module source code and configuration to enable DKMS to do its work.

Comment: Tried this today, actually had Module bbswitch not found, but was getting good battery life. I tried the Answer and now I get module not found, but terrible battery life...