# bbswitch does not work on ASUS A93S

Tags: bbswitch

I've tried the suggestions given in an earlier answer to a similar question (see [elsewhere on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130917/bumblebee-module-bbswitch-could-not-be-loaded)), but it does not work.

Both

```
lsmod | grep nouveau
lsmod | grep bbs
```

come up empty.

I am running Precise on an ASUS A93S and installed bbswitch-dkms from the bumblebee/stable repository.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, it is not enough to just install `bbswitch-dkms`. Maybe a manual initramfs afterwards will do the trick. What does definitely do the trick, however, is to follow the guide on the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) and do the following, if you just want bumblebee for power saving:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends bumblebee
```

After I did that, the power meter dropped from 45W to 30W!