# Cannot install bumblebee to the Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

If I try to install bumblebee with following command:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

I face with following output end with double error

```
Need to get 0 B/60.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 240 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package bumblebee.
(Reading database ... 417120 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking bumblebee (from .../bumblebee_3.1-1~quantalppa1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package bumblebee-nvidia.
Unpacking bumblebee-nvidia (from .../bumblebee-nvidia_3.1-1~quantalppa1_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up bumblebee (3.1-1~quantalppa1) ...
Adding members from group(s) 'adm sudo admin' to 'bumblebee':
erogol
Adding user erogol to group bumblebee
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
FATAL: Module bbswitch not found.
invoke-rc.d: initscript bumblebeed, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing bumblebee (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bumblebee-nvidia:
 bumblebee-nvidia depends on bumblebee (= 3.1-1~quantalppa1); however:
  Package bumblebee is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing bumblebee-nvidia (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-24-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bumblebee
 bumblebee-nvidia
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I could not find out the reason. Is there any suggestion for the error?

Comment: Try manually running `dpkg --configure bumblebee`. Paste the output either in a code block or in a linked web paste from e.g. Pastebin.

Comment: I did not work and here is the output http://paste.ubuntu.com/5609119/

Answer (score 1):

Try following the instructions in the top answer in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130917/bumblebee-module-bbswitch-could-not-be-loaded). To summarize:

Do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bbswitch-dkms
```

then if that doesn't work,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and then finally if even that doesn't work, install the headers for your specific kernel version:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Sorry but does not work. I did what have you written but when I try t install bumblebee it cannot complete the installation and it just freezing.

Comment: Does it give an error?