# how to fix bumblebee after a package upgrade?

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, bbswitch

I have been having issues with bumblebee after a <strike>kernel</strike> package upgrade. It started in 12.04 and has been carried on into 13.04.

Basically it is outlined as follows; after a clean install of ubuntu (no matter the release), i install bumblebee and it works well out of the box. <strike>When the kernel is upgraded (e.g. from 3.8.0-19 to 3.8.0-22),</strike> After some time, bumblebee breaks with the following error in */var/log/syslog*:

```
     kernel: [ 4.135691] bbswitch: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
     bumblebeed[1259]: Module bbswitch could not be loaded (timeout?)
     bumblebeed[1259]: No switching method available. The dedicated card will always be on.
     bumblebeed[1259]: /usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
```

The output of *bumblebeed --v*:

```
     [ 3326.529062] [DEBUG]Found card: 01:00.0 (discrete)
     [ 3326.529106] [DEBUG]Found card: 00:02.0 (integrated)
     [ 3326.529121] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
     [ 3326.529739] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia
     [ 3326.529767] [DEBUG]Skipping auto-detection, using configured driver 'nvidia'
     [ 3326.529986] [DEBUG]Process /sbin/modprobe started, PID 4986.
     [ 3326.530101] [DEBUG]Hiding stderr for execution of /sbin/modprobe
     [ 3326.533252] [DEBUG]SIGCHILD received, but wait failed with No child processes
     [ 3326.533715] [INFO]Loading driver bbswitch (module bbswitch)
     [ 3326.533961] [DEBUG]Process modprobe started, PID 4987.
     ERROR: could not insert 'bbswitch': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
     [ 3326.537523] [DEBUG]Process with PID 4987 returned code 1
     [ 3326.537888] [ERROR]Module bbswitch could not be loaded (timeout?)
     [ 3326.537936] [DEBUG]bbswitch is not available, perhaps you need to insmod it?
     [ 3326.537993] [INFO]Skipping switcheroo PM method because it is not explicitly selected in the configuration.
     [ 3326.538022] [WARN]No switching method available. The dedicated card will always be on.
     [ 3326.538047] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
     [ 3326.538078] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
     [ 3326.538100] [DEBUG] X display: :8
     [ 3326.538122] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/nvidia-304:/usr/lib32/nvidia-304
     [ 3326.538150] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
     [ 3326.538172] [DEBUG] pidfile: /var/run/bumblebeed.pid
     [ 3326.538207] [DEBUG] xorg.conf file: /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
     [ 3326.538238] [DEBUG] xorg.conf.d dir: /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d
     [ 3326.538260] [DEBUG] ModulePath: /usr/lib/nvidia-304/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
     [ 3326.538282] [DEBUG] GID name: bumblebee
     [ 3326.538306] [DEBUG] Power method: auto
     [ 3326.538328] [DEBUG] Stop X on exit: 1
     [ 3326.538354] [DEBUG] Driver: nvidia
     [ 3326.538375] [DEBUG] Driver module: nvidia-304
     [ 3326.538402] [DEBUG] Card shutdown state: 1
     [ 3326.538635] [DEBUG]Process /sbin/modprobe started, PID 4988.
     [ 3326.538722] [DEBUG]Hiding stderr for execution of /sbin/modprobe
     [ 3326.541954] [DEBUG]SIGCHILD received, but wait failed with No child processes
     [ 3326.542076] [DEBUG]Configuration test passed.
     [ 3326.542196] [ERROR]Daemon already running, pid 1292
```

The output of *dmesg | grep bbswitch*:

```
     bbswitch: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
```

The output of *dkms bbswitch status*:

```
     bbswitch, 0.7, 3.8.0-19-generic, x86_64: installed
     bbswitch, 0.7, 3.8.0-22-generic, x86_64: installed
```

This issue has recently been posted [here](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/429) but no solution has been posted.
Also it is different from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130917/bumblebee-module-bbswitch-could-not-be-loaded?rq=1) issue.

Currently, the only workaround i have found so far is redoing a clean install of ubuntu, upgrading to the lastest kernel version and then installing bumblebee. After this it works fine, until the next <strike>kernel</strike> bumblebee upgrade where it will break again and i have to redo the installation. This is far from optimal as i have to do this approximately every 2 weeks :(.

Some info:

```
     Ubuntu 13.04; kernel version 3.8.0-22-generic
     Clevo W150HR, i7 2630QM, NV GT555M, 8GB RAM, SSD+HDD
```

Anybody any ideas on how to fix this?

Edit: It turns out to be an issue with an outdated version of gcc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with older versions of gcc as discussed [here](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/429).

Under gcc 4.4 the install will break where as it works on gcc 4.7+.